# Combining different raters scores

Tags: psychometrics, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

In my experiment two raters evaluate 100 products, both expressing an "innovation score" on a likert scale (range is 1 to 5, where 1 is "not innovative" and 5 is "disruptive innovation").

I calculated a weighted Cohen's Kappa and the inter-rater agreement is very good (k=0.7).

Now I need to combine the two ratings into one single score for each product.
I saw that many studies (dealing with other measures) are combining scores using their average. I would rather use the sum of the two ratings?

Could you suggest me what is best (between mean score, sum, etc..) and why? Could you also provide some reference I could use to support my choice?

Comment: The answer to this question will depend on what decisions you wish to make on the final measure.  These could be combined by adding, multiplying, or averaging (to briefly touch on this topic). If this is just part of an analysis and the next step depends on a greater variance or on normal data, then how you combine them might be important.